# Run jQuery on External pages/debugging jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, external-process

I am a beginner at jQuery. I am trying to practice as many functions as i can. BUT i am tired to write HTML for all this stuff. So is there any way i can run jQuery functions on any page as in google.com or any other site, any chrome extension ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem with me, when i started using jQuery. But i found an excellent chrome extension for that.Its called jsshell.Here is the 
[link](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/kmgmkbicahmbceidoidjbkbpkfogaldh)
and yes, it has a Auto Complete feature which i love very much. :)

Comment: is it just me or did anyone else read that as "jss hell" just now? O_o

Answer (score 2):

js console for one.  If the site has jquery (like StackOverflow) you can press ctrl-shift-j to open up the console and directly run jquery commands. otherwise there's jsfiddle.net.

Answer (score 0):

Try http://jsfiddle.net/. JsFiddle is a playground for web developers

Comment: how can i run scripts on other pages using jsfiddle ?